Alphabet column of letters missing from macOS Contacts app?
The alphabet column of letters on the right edge of the list of contact names is missing from macOS Contacts app. It still exists on the iCloud.com website and on iPhone. Reboot does not bring it back. Is it still visible on your Mac? Is this by design? Can I do something to bring it back? My MacBook is running macOS 14.5 Sonoma.

What version number and or build is your macOS?

My MacBook is running macOS 14.5 Sonoma.
